# Chrome on surface tablet disable sweep after pinch zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, gesture

On an app I'm building I need to disable zooming and scrolling which I did with the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'>
```

It all works fine if I try to sweep with one finger but when I use 2 fingers to pinch and one of them lifts up from the screen the scrolling gets enabled until I lift the second finger from the screen as well! Also, while keeping one finger on, if I touch with the second one and pinch, it will zoom as well...

I've tried to add preventdefault on gesturechange but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Here is some code I've already used:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
document.body.addEventListener('gesturechange', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale="1.0", maximum-scale="1.0", user-scalable="no">
```

Set user scalable as no.